# Page cleaner took ms to flush pages/WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use

Tags: mysql, galera, xtradb-cluster

I am running percona xtradb cluster 8.0.  One of my nodes went down, when I try to bring it up.  The log says the transfer is complete and joined.

```
0.0 (DB404): State transfer from 3.0 (DB403) complete.
[Galera] Shifting JOINER -> JOINED (TO: 799642)
```

However looking at the `wsrep_local_state_comment` status says joining.  The `wsrep_cluster_size` has 5 which is the total amount including the bad node.  Also showing all incoming ip addresses as well. `wsrep_ready` is off but I am guessing that is because it is still joining.
The log file also fills up with

```
[InnoDB] Page cleaner took 11974ms to flush 474 pages
```

And the node never fully joins the cluster.  When I try to query I get `WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use` Any advice would be appreciated.

Page cleaner took ms to flush pages/WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use

I just let it run for about 22 hours and it finally has fully joined.  Page clearer still fires every so often.  No real resolution, it just started working.  I am thinking it some sort of hardware related issue, or could be bad software install.

Comment: What kind of app?  What kind of schema?  (eg EAV)  How many queries per second?

Comment: I am just trying to join the cluster.  No one can query the node.

Comment: What is going on in the other nodes?

Comment: The other nodes are working as expected.  No issues at all. I checked just now and page cleaner message is still running and the bad node still has joining as its status.  The `wsrep_local_recv_queue` is going down.  It was at 900 yesterday now it is at 112.